Fixed masked-image background-color with scrollable background image?
I'm building a small website with a rather particular background.
My goal is to apply a masked background image gradient to the repeated background image pattern (flowers.png), in a way that the gradient background would stay fixed, and the patterns would change to match it while the user scrolls.
The gradient background color would always be the size of the screen, so the flowers would be pink at the bottom of the screen and change to yellow while they get scrolled to the top.
My current try is not working, as the flowers are staying white, but I don't even know if this is feasible, or if there would be a simpler way to do what I need.


.visitors-layout {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.visitors-layout .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: grey;
}


/* This will scroll with the content */

.visitors-layout::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600/300");
  background-size: 600px 300px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.visitors-layout::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(255, 229, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 239, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;
  mask-image: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(255, 229, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 239, 1) 100%);
  mask-attachment: fixed;
}
<body class="visitors-layout">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>This is a simple HTML + CSS template!</h1>

    <p>
      Mumblecore fam flexitarian, hoodie skateboard blackbird spyplane kickstarter pop-up pinterest selvage you probably haven't heard of them tumeric. Try-hard woke flexitarian keytar scenester offal. Pork belly flexitarian copper mug big mood fanny pack prism.
      Cardigan gorpcore crucifix bruh, irony church-key helvetica try-hard woke mixtape. Taxidermy godard seitan, bruh authentic edison bulb air plant vibecession kitsch flannel. Intelligentsia etsy single-origin coffee authentic. Marxism microdosing
      chambray echo park, jianbing subway tile tacos chartreuse knausgaard.
    </p>

    <p>
      Echo park art party blackbird spyplane swag readymade sartorial lyft fashion axe PBR&B same offal iceland drinking vinegar VHS viral. Fingerstache venmo plaid yes plz four loko swag cupping vape praxis chambray hell of retro drinking vinegar fixie umami.
      Sartorial green juice hoodie salvia. Bruh tumeric echo park photo booth. Mustache gatekeep yuccie, pop-up sriracha photo booth banh mi jawn lo-fi four dollar toast chambray shaman. Gastropub yr yuccie PBR&B keffiyeh seitan. Keytar neutra vape bushwick
      crucifix snackwave squid dreamcatcher hella biodiesel etsy XOXO.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>




Please provide a proper [mre] directly within your question; do not (just) link to external sandboxes / playgrounds.

@C3roe apologies, I edited my question

A mask-image works on the element that you apply it on. Applied to ::after, it will not have any effect on what ::before contains.

Ok so since I want one element to fit the viewport and another to fit the page's content, I guess that's not feasible. Thanks

Maybe you can use mask-size to specify the size of the masking background - if you do it with 100vh?

@Jaeger Just the flowers should be colored right? Are you able to link or at least describe the flower.png including the flower and background? You can blend the color of the gradient and the image if set up correctly.
